# finding duplicate elemntes in a list with LISP language

Tags: lisp

I'm new Lisp programmer and need some help
I want to write a function that find duplicate elements in a list but i cant write it.
I need something like this in lisp:

```
for(int i=0; i < myList.length(); i++)  
   for(int j=i+1; j < myList.Length(); j++)
   {  
      if(myList[i] == myList[j])  
         cout << myList[i] << endl;
   }
```

Anybody can help me?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a place to have others translate code for you from one language to another. It is expected that you show **effort** to solve your problem, which better be an actual problem related to programming. Don't post questions for which **you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)**

Comment: Your Algol code doesn't find duplicate elements in a list. Eg. for `(1 2 1 1)` it prints `"1\n1\n1\n2\n1\n1\n1\n"`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 2 lists and want to find the duplicates in both, why don't use `intersection` for doing set-intersections:

```
(intersection '(a b c d) '(d f g c)) ;; => (D C)
```

You can then do a `cdr` on your second list if you only care about its tail:

```
(intersection '(a b c d) (cdr '(d f g c))) ;; => (C)
```

Answer (score 0):

Several ways to skin this cat, here's one method,

```
(defun dupes (lst)
  (cond ((null lst) '())
        ((member (car lst) (cdr lst)) (cons (car lst) (dupes (cdr lst))))
        (t (dupes (cdr lst)))))
```

Note that a direct translation of your original code would be best written using the `LOOP` macro. But the above is a start for you.

Answer (score 0):

if you use scheme language, you may construct functions with tail recursion. Example:

```
;; this function collect list items, which
;; included into input-list more than once
(define (duplicates input-list)
  ;; declare nested core function
  (define (core lst acc)
    ;; cond is like c++ expression:
    ;; if () ...
    ;; else if () ...
    ;; ...
    ;; else ...
    (cond ((null? lst)
           ;; if list is empty, return accumulator
           acc)
          ((member (car lst) (cdr lst))
           ;; if head of list will exist in tail of list
           ;; call new iteration with accumulate head of list
           ;; and remove it from the tail
           (core (remove* (list (car lst)) lst) (cons (car lst) acc)))
          ;; else new iteration with tail of list
          (else
           (core (cdr lst) acc))))
  ;; now we call core function
  (core input-list '()))
```

scheme compiler (or interpreter) will optimize tail calls as cycle. If you write on common lisp, your implementation most likely have TCO (tail call optimization) and this code may be faster than 'recursion with return':

```
;;; function return list of duplicates
;;; &optional keyword say's that 'argument by default'
(defun duplicates (lst &optional acc)
  (cond ((null lst)
          acc)
        ((member (car lst) (cdr lst))
         (duplicates (remove (car lst) lst) (cons (car lst) acc)))
        (t
         (duplicates (cdr lst) acc))))
```

it is the same functions writen in different lisp languages.